# jQuery back to last page

Tags: jquery

I have a multi-page form, and I'm trying to implement "Back" buttons, so that the form will go back, just the same behavior as the browser's back button, and still retain everything in the fields, rather than clearing them. How can I do this?

Comment: Depends, are your forms on different pages? Or the same page and dynamically hidden/shown? Or in tabs? Would be helpful if you posted your pertinent code so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.history(-1); //plain ol' javascript
```

Comment: In IE the fields would not be preserved though, he wants the form to maintained a filled state when they navigate backwards

Comment: @Chad then the OP has to somehow save them to the server (but idk what server the OP has, so i can't answer that part)

Comment: That is why I asked what I did in my comment on his post; the solution depends a lot on how he implemented his forms. If they are all on the same page you can implement a solution easily with some JavaScript. If they are on different pages then it will take some server-side variables to store the information between posts.

Comment: @Chad dont assume the OP is a `he` :-p

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this discussion/solution offers a solution for you: https://superuser.com/questions/269394/ie7-doesnt-retain-form-input-when-back-button-is-used